# Why does my <div> element start shaking when I try to move it?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to Stack Overflow.
I have a simple webpage which tries to move a colored div element back and forth.
However when I run it the div element starts moving correctly but after a few seconds it starts shaking madly, as if its boss refused to give it the salary.
Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Move</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\Web\CSS\CSS.css"/>
    <script src="D:\Web\JS\JS.js">
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="box">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {

  var x = 0;

  var box = document.getElementById("box");
  setInterval(moveRight, 5);

  function moveRight() {
    if(x >= 150) {
      clearInterval();
      setInterval(moveLeft, 5);
    } else {
      x += 1;
      box.style.left = x + "px";
    }
  }

  function moveLeft() {
    if(x <= 0) {
      clearInterval();
      setInterval(moveRight, 5);
    } else {
      x -= 1;
      box.style.left = x + "px";
    }
  }

}
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #246;
}

#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #268;
  position: relative;
}

#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #2ac;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Plz help me
Thanks

Comment: [Here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdPvKd) of your solution and it seems fine, you'll have to give more detail.

Comment: you can do that animation with only `CSS` !

Comment: `clearInterval();` does absolutely nothing. Please read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) on how to use `clearInterval` correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not clearing the interval since you're not passing a variable to it, therefore it's not doing anything. If you set the interval to a variable, you can clear the interval when you switch the direction.

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Here's an example:

```js
(function() {
  var direction;
  var x = 0;
  var box = document.getElementById("box");

  // set the initial direction
  direction = setInterval(moveRight, 5);

  function moveRight() {
    if (x >= 150) {
      clearInterval(direction);
      direction = setInterval(moveLeft, 5);
    } else {
      x += 1;
      box.style.left = x + "px";
    }
  }

  function moveLeft() {
    if (x <= 0) {
      clearInterval(direction);
      direction = setInterval(moveRight, 5);
    } else {
      x -= 1;
      box.style.left = x + "px";
    }
  }
})();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #246;
}

#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #268;
  position: relative;
}

#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #2ac;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Move</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="box">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I never expected my mistake to be something as simple as this. :D